# How to avoid using POpen in boto on Google App Engine?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, boto3

Google App engine does not support file I/O or other low level library.

I want to be able to use boto (1.9.167) library in my project on GAE.

Now I encountered this error:

```
(/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/a19f7fde5f64c33c/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:269)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/a19f7fde5f64c33c/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/a19f7fde5f64c33c/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 311, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/a19f7fde5f64c33c/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~my-project/app:v2-0-281.418863766814079756/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    from project import (
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~my-project/app:v2-0-281.418863766814079756/src/project/upload_api.py", line 5, in <module>
    import boto3
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~my-project/app:v2-0-281.418863766814079756/lib/boto3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~my-project/app:v2-0-281.418863766814079756/lib/boto3/session.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~my-project/app:v2-0-281.418863766814079756/lib/botocore/session.py", line 30, in <module>
    import botocore.credentials
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~my-project/app:v2-0-281.418863766814079756/lib/botocore/credentials.py", line 774, in <module>
    class ProcessProvider(CredentialProvider):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~my-project/app:v2-0-281.418863766814079756/lib/botocore/credentials.py", line 778, in ProcessProvider
    def __init__(self, profile_name, load_config, popen=subprocess.Popen):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Popen'
```

Is it possible to, for example, skip `credentials` checking and hence bypass the call to `Popen`?

My code is simply

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                         aws_access_key_id=access_key,
                         aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
s3_client.generate_presigned_url(...)
```

There is no dependency on any file stored locally.

Comment: The easiest solution is to use the latest version of boto2.

Comment: Can you shed more light on this suggestion? e.g. Which API to use? Also (not knowing enough the background) will boto2 be replaced by boto3 eventually?

Comment: boto3 has replaced boto2, but boto2 works on GAE and boto3 does not.  If boto2 meets your needs then you are all set.  If not, then you'll need to modify boto3 to make it work on GAE which is probably not an easy task.